# Number of pages in a word doc in java

Tags: java, ms-word

Is there an easy way to count the number of pages is a Word document either .doc or .docx?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could try the Apache API for word Docs:

http://poi.apache.org/

It as a method for getting the page count:

```
public int getPageCount()
```

**Returns**:
The page count or 0 if the SummaryInformation does not contain a page count.

Answer (score 17):

I found a really cool class, that count Pages for **Word**, Excel and PowerPoint. With help of Apache POI. And it is for old doc and new docx.

```
String lowerFilePath = filePath.toLowerCase();
if (lowerFilePath.endsWith(".xls")) {
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(lowerFilePath));
            Integer sheetNums = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
            if (sheetNums > 0) {
                return workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRowBreaks().length + 1;
            }
        } else if (lowerFilePath.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
            XSSFWorkbook xwb = new XSSFWorkbook(lowerFilePath);
            Integer sheetNums = xwb.getNumberOfSheets();
            if (sheetNums > 0) {
                return xwb.getSheetAt(0).getRowBreaks().length + 1;
            }
        } else if (lowerFilePath.endsWith(".docx")) {
            XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(POIXMLDocument.openPackage(lowerFilePath));
            return docx.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getPages();
        } else if (lowerFilePath.endsWith(".doc")) {
            HWPFDocument wordDoc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(lowerFilePath));
            return wordDoc.getSummaryInformation().getPageCount();
        } else if (lowerFilePath.endsWith(".ppt")) {
            HSLFSlideShow document = new HSLFSlideShow(new FileInputStream(lowerFilePath));
            SlideShow slideShow = new SlideShow(document);
            return slideShow.getSlides().length;
        } else if (lowerFilePath.endsWith(".pptx")) {
            XSLFSlideShow xdocument = new XSLFSlideShow(lowerFilePath);
            XMLSlideShow xslideShow = new XMLSlideShow(xdocument);
            return xslideShow.getSlides().length;
}
```

source: [OfficeTools.getPageCount()](http://haaprojects.googlecode.com/svn/HAAProject_POITest/src/main/java/org/haaproject/poitest/OfficeTools.java)

Comment: How did you implement Apache POI in build gradle?

Comment: Could you please share your gradle? I'm not able to implement it correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Use Apache POI's [SummaryInformation](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hpsf/SummaryInformation.html) to fetch the Total page count of a MS word document

Answer (score 5):

```
  //Library is aspose 
  //package com.aspose.words.*

/*Open the Word Document */

Document doc = new Document("C:\\Temp\\file.doc"); 

/*Get page count */

int pageCount = doc.getPageCount();
```

Answer (score -1):

docx4j can get total pages as below:

```
org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsExtendedPart docPropsExtendedPart = wordMLPkg.getDocPropsExtendedPart();
org.docx4j.docProps.extended.Properties extendedProps = (org.docx4j.docProps.extended.Properties)docPropsExtendedPart.getJaxbElement();
int numPages = extendedProps.getPages();
```