# Fastest Way to Read Number of Pages of Docx Files in Java (After Word Rendering)?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, docx4j

I create docx files using docx4j. After document creation I need to know the number of pages.

I know that I can read the persisted number of pages using docx4j as follows:

```
final WordprocessingMLPackage doc = ... // read doc
org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsExtendedPart docPropsExtendedPart = doc .getDocPropsExtendedPart();
org.docx4j.docProps.extended.Properties extendedProps = docPropsExtendedPart.getJaxbElement();
final Integer pages = extendedProps.getPages();
```

but it always returns `1` because that's the number of pages that is persisted to the docx file. Apache POI obviously returns the same result ([XWPFDocument returning 1 number of pages for docx file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44650147/5207900)).

When you open the document with Word you can notice that the number of pages is steadily updated for the first few seconds (which confirms that the initial number of pages is `1` and Word updates it dynamically after applying the styles etc. that influence the number of pages).

I read that you can convert it to PDF first and then read the number of pages. The [sample PDF conversion provided by docx4j on github](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutPDF.java) uses a commercial PDF converter so I cannot reuse this code. Furthermore, converting it to PDF first seems cumbersome and unnecessarily time-consuming to me.

**Question**: What is the fastest way to read the number of pages of docx files in Java without using commercial software?

*//Edit:* 
The question [Number of pages in a word doc in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2848514/5207900) unfortunately doesn't help me. As I wrote above, apache POI (and other APIs) only read the persisted number of pages (which is 1). What I need is the actual number of pages as Word would display it when you actually open the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of pages in a word doc in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848514/number-of-pages-in-a-word-doc-in-java)

Comment: @Lakshan Thanks for the link but unfortunately it doesn't. Both, apache POI and aspose  only read the persisted number of pages, which appears to be always 1. It only gets updated when you actually open the document with Word.

Comment: Short of writing an open source rendering engine for DOCX files, you're going to struggle.... The DOCX format is run-based, not page-based like PDF, so the format itself doesn't have the info. Maybe call OpenOffice from Java via JODConverter to have it rendered then query OO for the page count?

Comment: There is no way in my opinion. The pages only can be count after rendering the document. I do not know any good `Word` document renderer which is not commercial software. Even the  `PDF` approach cannot work properly for all possible "Word" documents, as all non-commercial "Word" to "PDF" converters that I know of so far had major shortcomings.

Comment: Based on the comments, the fastest way to get the number of pages would be for someone to bring the document up in Word, and yell to you the number of pages.  Sometimes, the old ways are the better ways.

Comment: Note that I meanwhile also tested Aspose.Words (v20.3). It gives me a page count > 1 but it's always wrong. It's always lower than the page count displayed by Microsoft Word. Furthermore, Aspose doesn't seems to be free (there is just a free trial).

Comment: I'd say this endeavour is bound to fail. The number of pages depend on the font being used, which the document does not embed. It follows that no faithful rendering can be done (fail-proofly) outside of the original author's computer, and thus, no faithful page count can be produced. Any converter might provide a reasonnable guess, but not the actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use documents4j (though this needs Word); see https://www.docx4java.org/blog/2020/03/documents4j-for-toc-update/

You may need to customise word_convert.vbs a little more.